# Parsing ZonedDateTime.parse ignoring offset

Tags: java, date, zoneddatetime, java-time

I'm trying to parse `22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+01` using the format `dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss zX` - but irrespective of the offset, the ZonedDateTime created is the same.

An example to reproduce this is below, where I am programatically altering the offset:

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss zX")
    .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Current time is \"{0}\"", formatter.format(Instant.now())));

for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    final String str = String.format("22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+%02d", i);
    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Parsed String \"{0}\", got result of \"{1}\"", str,
        ZonedDateTime.parse(str, formatter)));

}
```

And the output:

```
Current time is "12/07/19 12:59:25 ZZ"
Parsed String "22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+01", got result of "2017-04-22T09:24:28Z[UTC]"
Parsed String "22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+02", got result of "2017-04-22T09:24:28Z[UTC]"
Parsed String "22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+03", got result of "2017-04-22T09:24:28Z[UTC]"
Parsed String "22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+04", got result of "2017-04-22T09:24:28Z[UTC]"
Parsed String "22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+05", got result of "2017-04-22T09:24:28Z[UTC]"
Parsed String "22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+06", got result of "2017-04-22T09:24:28Z[UTC]"
Parsed String "22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+07", got result of "2017-04-22T09:24:28Z[UTC]"
Parsed String "22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+08", got result of "2017-04-22T09:24:28Z[UTC]"
Parsed String "22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+09", got result of "2017-04-22T09:24:28Z[UTC]"
Parsed String "22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+10", got result of "2017-04-22T09:24:28Z[UTC]"
Parsed String "22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+11", got result of "2017-04-22T09:24:28Z[UTC]"
Parsed String "22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+12", got result of "2017-04-22T09:24:28Z[UTC]"
```

Note how irrespective of the offset, the result is identical.

Comment: @SeanBright if I do that it doesn't work at all. ``Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+01' could not be parsed at index 18``

Comment: `zX` certainly does not match `UTC+01`. `z` matches time zone names, like `PST` or `Pacific Standard Time`. `UTC+<num>` are not timezone names. `X` matches time zone offsets, but not in the format `+01` I believe.  The `O` format seems to want `UTC+01:00` not `UTC+01`...

Comment: I suspect you want `'UTC'x`.

Comment: `z` matches UTC and `X` matches `+01`. When parsing into a `ZonedDateTime`, it picks the zone, UTC, and ignores the offset, +01. My guess would be that parsing into an `OffsetDateTime` it would be the other way around.

Comment: Wouldn't changing `UTC+%02d` to `+%02d` and then using `x` instead of `'UTC'x` be same thing at that point?

Comment: @SeanBright I had the same thought and tried `O` (uppercase letter oh). It failed. `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+07' could not be parsed at index 18`. So either it objects to `UTC` or to the leading zero of the hours or both.

Comment: @Nexevis In the example code shown here, yes.  The question implies that the strings are actually coming from another source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your string I take `UTC+01` to be an offset of +1 hour from UTC. So while UTC might have been interpreted as a time zone (which it really isn’t), that is not relevant here since the time in your string is not in UTC but in UTC+01:00. So we shouldn’t use `z`, time-zone name, for parsing it. Doing that was basically what gave you the wrong result (in combination with parsing into a `ZonedDateTime`).

@VGR is correct in his/her comment: we want `'UTC'x`. I am using just two examples, that suffices for demonstrating that they give different results.

```
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss 'UTC'x");

    String str = "22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+01";
    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Parsed String \"{0}\", got result of \"{1}\"",
            str, OffsetDateTime.parse(str, formatter)));
    str = "22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+07";
    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Parsed String \"{0}\", got result of \"{1}\"",
            str, OffsetDateTime.parse(str, formatter)));
```

Output is:

> ```
> Parsed String "22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+01", got result of "2017-04-22T09:24:28+01:00"
> Parsed String "22/04/17 09:24:28 UTC+07", got result of "2017-04-22T09:24:28+07:00"
> ```

The single quotes around `UTC` denote literal text, so the formatter checks that the text is there but assings no meaning to it. One `x` is offset consisting of just hour (unless non-zero minutes had been part of the offset), for example `+01` or `+12`. Since your string contains an offset and no time zone (such as for example Europe/London for British time), `OffsetDateTime` is the (most) correct type for representing your date and time.

Stepping a step back, while your format is perfectly human readable, it is non-standard and not well suitable for parsing by machines. You may want to consider whether you can persuade the sender of the string to give you ISO 8601 format instead, for example `2017-04-22T09:24:28+01:00`.

Link: [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)